# Can "human exclusion zones" in national parks for preserving Wolves and Grizzlies be a good idea?

Tags: ecology, population-dynamics, conservation-biology

There are National Preserves in the National Parks where some human activities are permitted. But can it make sense to create "exclusion zones" so no human would be permitted in a certain area, not even scientists or researchers just so Grizzlies and Wolves can have a whole world to themselves ?

I know we won't be able to find out how those species are doing, but would there be any benefit ? Has any country ever tried that ?

Comment: Good idea from what perspective/for whom? For species conservation, the ecosystem, the individual animals ("*..a whole world to themselves*"), humans (having untouched ecosystems), Gaia?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a neat idea that should be discussed.
Not just for wolves or large predators but for all wildlife situations
There should be small habitats for all wildlife to refuge scattered around. Of course national parks, reserves and refuges are there for this purpose, but humans have become far too abundant on this planet to coexist anymore, and maybe we need to take it a step further? Again, it's something that should be discussed and awareness made of the issue.

And by far the best reason for this if nothing else is to have a scientific "control" spot for environmental research. It is important to have a control in all experiments, and to have a human exclusion zone helps create that control. If we had that, maybe someone could actually prove how much humans really are screwing up the planet, or maybe someone will prove they aren't :D